# Solid Noise Generation in C++

Tags: c++, noise, simplex

So I have been using my Google'ing skills to study Perlin and Simplex noise, and have come across a lot of articles that are a bit math heavy for myself. I've also come across a lot of code, but it seems to be either in C# or Java, neither of which I am familiar enough to be able to extrapolate how the noise is actually generated.

My goal is to find some code that will generate solid noise, similar to the "Render Clouds" function in GIMP, as shown below:

[image]

Now it doesn't have to be anything fancy, I just want to be able to generate noise as shown above within my program.

Comment: You can't translate C# or Jave to C++? o.O

Comment: As I said, I dont know enough about the other two languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a nice Simplex Noise library in C++ that I was able to use, but thats for the suggestion jeremy :)

Link to C++ Simplex Noise: http://www.6by9.net/b/2012/02/03/simplex-noise-for-c-and-python

Answer (score 4):

[Cinder](http://libcinder.org/) is an excellent framework for writing graphical applications in C++. It has a built in [Perlin noise](http://libcinder.org/docs/v0.8.4/classcinder_1_1_perlin.html) class and is [currently very well maintained and has an active community](https://forum.libcinder.org/topic/perlin-noise-on-shader).

Interesting things done w/ Cinder and noise:

http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/laboratory/cinder/noise-reactive-particle-sphere
https://1024d.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/quartz-composer-cinder-plugin/
https://vimeo.com/37555124